# React Native - Firebase: How do I show user data in native react with firebase?

Tags: firebase, react-native

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4IaGU.png)

I have the following code, but it shows nothing

```
state = {
 items: []
}

componentWillMount() {
   const { uid } = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
   var usersRef = firebase.database().ref('/users/'+ uid);
   usersRef.once('value').then(snapshot => {
     items= snapshot.val()
   }); 
}
render() {
  const { items } = this.state;
  return (
    <View>
       <Text style={styles.name}>{items.nombre}</Text>
   </View>
  )}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to set the `snapshot.val()` to `this.state.items`, but you are not referencing `this.state.items` inside the usersRef call.

Try doing this in your `componentWillMount` -

```
componentWillMount() {
  const { uid } = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
  let usersRef = firebase.database().ref('/users/'+ uid);
  usersRef.once('value').then(snapshot => {
    this.setState({ items: snapshot.val() });
  }); 
}
```